# Fragment takes height as match parent inside frame layout with weight

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-layout-weight, android-framelayout

I have an Activity i which i have divided the views in weights as follows.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include
    android:id="@+id/header"
    layout="@layout/header" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp">
    </View>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".75"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container_frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_weight=".75" />
   </LinearLayout>

<include
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    layout="@layout/footer" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

First recycler view is visible and when user clicks on a button i am hiding recyclerview and making frame layout visible and loading the fragment into it.

My fragment xml code is this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/header_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/chat_header_background"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/chat_header_background"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/footer_fragment"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header_fragment"
    android:background="@color/chat_body_background">

 </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

So when i load the fragment into the frame layout the fragment doesn't fit into the frame layout weight, it takes height as match parent and my view with 0.25 weight gets hided. So how can i fix this. I want to show fragment to be visible only in the frame layout space.

Answer (score 0):

Use this fragment layout code..

**Forcefully create a linear layout a root layout and embed the relativeLayout inside it**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight=".75"
>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/header_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/chat_header_background"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/chat_header_background"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/footer_fragment"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header_fragment"
    android:background="@color/chat_body_background">

 </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight=".25">

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: in between header and footer i have to add a view, recycler view or framelayout

Comment: same issue as before?